# TinyMCE conflicting with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, tinymce

I have configured my server using htaccess so that I can route all URL's into a PHP $_GET parameter. I want the URLs on the site to finish with .htm. Currently I have this htaccess, and I have never had any problems with it:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ajax/([A-Z,a-z,0-9,\_/]*).htm$ index.php?route=$1&opformat=ajax [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([A-Z,a-z,0-9,\_/]*).htm$ index.php?route=$1 [QSA]
```

However I have just installed TinyMCE which uses .htm files in the js folder e.g. "/js/tinymce/prop.htm". For some reason when this URL is entered my htaccess routes it to php and it doesn't work.

I was given to understand that `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` should stop this from happening. Why is it not? `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` is working as I can go to "/js/tinymce" in this example and see directory listing.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to make sure, when you go to `"/js/tinymce/prop.htm"` you do actually get redirected to `"/js/tinymce/prop.php"`?

Comment: No I don't but that's not what's supposed to happen. Basically, my htaccess is supposed to rewrite "/foo/bar.htm" into "index.php?route=foo/bar"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change your code to this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ajax/([^.]*)\.htm$ index.php?route=$1&opformat=ajax [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^([^.]*)\.htm$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: wow, thanks. Do you mind explaining what you changed? Just for my own benefit

Comment: Sure. My first rule is basically saying **don't do anything** if it is for a file or directory. 2nd rule is forwarding `ajax/anytext.htm` to `index.php?route=anytext&opformat=ajax`. 3rd rule is forwarding `anytext.htm` to `index.php?route=anytext`. Important to use QSA flag for Query String Append and L for marking it last rule.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't seem to be working for me. I use your code and any file path just comes up with URL not found. If I take out the "RewriteRule ^ - [L]" line then it works, but only like before, and doesn't solve the original issue :S

Comment: Sorry I had some typo in my first rule and had conditions reversed. Please check the update and let me know if it works.